# python subprocess.call arguments issue

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, call

I am writing a simple python script under Linux to do a batch of concurrent single pings to hosts on my subnet using `subprocess`.

Manually the command works:
`ping -c 1 192.168.68.1`

The script::

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import call

path = "ping"
flags = "-c 1 "

for i in range(1,3):
    ip_addr = "192.168.68." + str(i)
    args = flags + ip_addr

    print "doing: {} {}".format(path, args)        
    call([path, args])
```

Commenting out call outputs the expected:

```
doing: ping -c 1 192.168.68.1
doing: ping -c 1 192.168.68.2
```

With `call()`, the script seems to call ping but with unknown arguments. Output as follows:

```
doing: ping -c 1 192.168.68.1
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
        [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
        [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
        [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
Usage: ping -6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
         [-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
         [-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
         [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
         [-W timeout] destination
doing: ping -c 1 192.168.68.2
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
        [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
        [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
        [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
Usage: ping -6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
         [-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
         [-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
         [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
         [-W timeout] destination
```

It seems `ping` is being called twice for each iteration with different `args` to what I expect. I note the `-6` argument ping complains about.
I would appreciate any help, particularly with regard to using `call()` properly.

**Update:**
Added bash script I'm attempting to emulate:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(seq 1 2); do
    ping -c 1 192.168.68.$ip &
done
```

Comment: `call([path, flags.strip(), ip_addr])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments passed to the function `call` should each be a single element in a list, as such:

```
call(['ping','-c','1','192.168.68.2'])
```

I could not reproduce the 'double printing' in my environment.

Comment: Hi Pablo, I have tried
`flags = ["-c", "1"]`
and then tried unpacking in the call()
`call([path, *flags, ip_addr])`
I get syntax error. Is it not possible to unpack within the array?

Comment: @user1330734: it is Python 3.5+ syntax.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Interestingly, the python code seem to be synchronous i.e. each ping call seems to wait for previous to complete. In contrast, the forking bash script I added above takes about 5 seconds to do IP range 1-254.

Comment: @user1330734  read the docs for subprocess.call(cmd)`. Think: what is the difference between `subprocess.Popen(cmd)` and subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()` and which one is closer to `subprocess.call(cmd)`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Thank you kindly for pointing me to the right place. In order to achieve concurrency, I need to call subprocess.Popen(cmd). `subprocess.call(cmd)` seems closer to `subprocess.Popen.wait()`. The python script now executes as expected, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pablo mentioned `flags`and `path` variables should be a list elements, so before calling the `call` method just convert your command string to list:

```
path = "ping"
flags = "-c 1"
cmd_list = [path] # convert string to list
cmd_list = cmd_list + flags.split(' ') # converting your flags string to list elements

call(cmd_list)
```